# Removing “Chapter” from chapter headings, change font and spacing, and center

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I’m using the book style in LaTeX. I want my chapter headings to look like this:

```
      1
 Great Chapter
```

It should be in the sans-serif and bold font, centered, and I want to be able to customize the spacing before and after the heading, and also customize the spacing between the “1” and the “Great Chapter.” How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Which document class do you use? Please provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `titlesec` package can facilitate all of this.

[image]

From the `titlesec` package

```
 \titlespacing{command}{left spacing}{before spacing}{after spacing}[right]
```

How to read `{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}`

- `12pt` is what we would like the spacing to be
- `plus 4pt` means that TeX can stretch it by at most `4pt`
- `minus 2pt` means that TeX can shrink it by at most `2pt`

This is one example of the concept of, 'glue', in TeX; it may seem strange to use the word 'glue' for a stretchable space, but to quote Knuth (The TeXbook)

> But whenever the author has suggested changing TeX's terminology,
>   numerous people have said that they like the word "glue" in spite of
>   its inappropriateness; so the original name has stuck.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

% custom chapter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}
{\thechapter\\[2cm]% spacing between number and Great chapter
#1}
{1pc}
{\Huge}
% From the titlesec package
% \titlespacing{command}{left spacing}{before spacing}{after spacing}[right]
% spacing: how to read {12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
%           12pt is what we would like the spacing to be
%           plus 4pt means that TeX can stretch it by at most 4pt
%           minus 2pt means that TeX can shrink it by at most 2pt
%       This is one example of the concept of, 'glue', in TeX
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*4}{-0.1cm}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Great chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, can you please tell me how I replace the pre-defined sizes (\Large, \LARGE, \huge, \HUGE) with a command where I can specify the font size exactly?

Comment: Or rather, how would I get the size that is, say, halfway between \huge and \Huge?

Comment: @Enchilada I think that's a separate question :) What do you mean by 'specify the font size exactly'?

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. I’ve put it in a separate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48208/obtain-the-size-between-huge-and-huge