# Obtain the size between \huge and \Huge

Tags: fontsize

How do I create a new sizing command command, `\semiHuge`, that is defined as being the size that lies between `\huge` and `\Huge`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The standard LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book`-- provide the following definitions of the directives `\huge` and `\Huge`:

- If the main font size is either `10pt` or `11pt`,

  ```
  \newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
  \newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
  ```
- and if the main font size is `12pt`, one finds

  ```
  \newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxvpt{30}}
  \let\Huge=\huge
  ```

  i.e., there's no difference between `\huge` and `\Huge` in this case.

Next, in the file `latex.ltx` (which contains the "LaTeX kernel"), one finds the following definitions of `\@xxpt` and `\@xxvpt`:

```
 \def\@xxpt{20.74}
 \def\@xxvpt{24.88}
```

The *geometric mean* of 20.74 and 24.88 is 22.72, and the geometric mean of 25 and 30 -- the baseline distances in effect for `\huge` and `\Huge` -- is 27.38. (See below for an explanation of why I choose the geometric mean.)

Thus, if you use either `10pt` or `11pt` as the size of the main text font, and if you use a font that's freely scalable, you could include the following instructions in your document's preamble to set up the directive `\semiHuge`:

```
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiHuge{\@setfontsize\semiHuge{22.72}{27.38}}}
\makeatother
```

This method of defining `\@setfontsize` is (marginally) safer than the more direct definition, viz., `\newcommand\semiHuge{\fontsize{22.72}{27.38}\selectfont}`, because `\@setfontsize` takes care not to mess with math font sizes.

Putting all this into an MWE, e.g.,

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} %% make CM font freely scalable
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiHuge{\@setfontsize\semiHuge{22.72}{27.38}}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\huge The quick huge fox jumps \ldots

\semiHuge The quick semiHuge fox jumps \ldots

\Huge The quick Huge fox jumps \ldots
\end{document}
```

one gets:

[image]

---

Lastly, you may ask why I take the *geometric* mean of the `\huge` and `\Huge` font sizes to arrive at the font size for `\semiHuge`. For a main text font size ("`\normalsize`") of `10pt`, LaTeX sets the ratio of adjoining font sizes -- `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, and `\Huge` -- is exactly 1.2. In addition, in LaTeX the exact font size for `11pt` is *not* `11.00` but `10.95`, i.e., the *geometric* mean of `10` and `12`. LaTeX's evident preference for keeping relative font sizes in tidy geometric progressions is what swayed me to go with the geometric mean of the sizes for `\huge` and `\Huge` to obtain the size for `\semiHuge`.

Left as an exercise for the reader: Design macros named `\semiLarge`, `\semiLARGE`, and `\semihuge`. :-)

Comment: Unless you load fix-cm or type1cm or use scalable fonts, a font size of 22.72 is not available, LaTeX will warn you that it is switching to size 20.74 so your semiHuge and huge only differ in baselineskip, not in font size. `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <22.72> not available
(Font)              size <20.74> substituted on input line 8.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- let me add the `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` instruction.

Comment: Based on `\newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt\@xivpt}` and `\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{16}}` [[1]](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fac/fac.cls); and given `\def\@xiipt{12}` and `\def\@xivpt{14.4}` [[2]](https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf); it seems the geometric means of these are 13.15 and 15.18 respectively.  Hence, we can define `\semiLarge` as `\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.15}{15.18}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this path to make semiFontsizes. I would like to suggest the following sizes:

```
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\semiHuge{\@setfontsize\semiHuge{22.72}{27.38}}
\newcommand\semihuge{\@setfontsize\semihuge{18.93}{23.45}}
\newcommand\semiLARGE{\@setfontsize\semiLARGE{15.77}{19.90}}
\newcommand\semiLarge{\@setfontsize\semiLarge{13.15}{15.87}}% 15.18?
\newcommand\semilarge{\@setfontsize\semilarge{11.46}{13.80}}
\newcommand\seminormal{\@setfontsize\seminormal{10.46}{12.77}}
\makeatother
```

Please feel free to prove the numbers of the geoemtric means.