# How to put as a title of a chapter, the name of the chapter instead of "Chapter"?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am using the structure

```
\chapter{aa}

\section{bb}

\subsection{cc}
```

So, it compiles it as:

> Chapter 1
>
> aa
>
> 1.1 bb
>
> 1.1.1 cc

But I would like to get:

> 1 aa
>
> 1.1 bb
>
> 1.1.1 cc

Although it is a simple thing, I have not been able to figure out what is the code for this. Any idea?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? And what about packages for sectioning like [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or...

Comment: \documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{anysize}

Comment: Related: [Remove “chapter #” from the chapter title but keep chapter number in the table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30530/5764)

Comment: Related: [Removing “Chapter” from chapter headings, change font and spacing, and center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48053/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove 'Chapter' text from chapter headings and have chapter number on the same line as chapter title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88238/5764); Original source: [Chapter formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18604/5764)